# Whats the best SQLite data type for a long string

Tags: sql, sqlite

In SQLite3 I am going to be storing a very long string that looks something like this:

```
string linkList = "www.blah.com,www.meh.com,www.hah.com";
```

will definitely exceed 255 chars, will probably be over 1000 chars

Should the column `linkList` be a `varchar`, [`TEXT`](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#storage_classes_and_datatypes) or something else to store a string that will probably be longer than 1000 chars

```
CREATE TABLE(uId INT PRIMARY KEY, linkList varchar);
```

**What would be the best variable type to use for the column `linkList`?**

Comment: `TEXT` is the standard data type. You could compress it and then put it in a `BLOB`, if you care about the storage requirements (or you could just compress the database).

Comment: Can someone store paragraphs , if so, what is the max limit , will it reduces  performance of app?

Comment: Every table column has a type affinity (one of BLOB, TEXT, INTEGER, REAL, or NUMERIC). so it varchar and text are same https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Answer (score 75, accepted):

#### You should [use `TEXT`](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html#storage_classes_and_datatypes).

Although, that's the same thing as `VARCHAR`:

> If the declared type of the column contains any of the strings "CHAR", "CLOB", or "TEXT" then that column has TEXT affinity. Notice that the type VARCHAR contains the string "CHAR" and is thus assigned TEXT affinity

And also:

> Note that numeric arguments in parentheses that following the type name (ex: "VARCHAR(255)") are ignored by SQLite - SQLite does not impose any length restrictions (other than the large global SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH limit) on the length of strings, BLOBs or numeric values.

***"SQLite does not impose any length restrictions"***

Answer (score 31):

Actually, all data types in SQLite is no matter, all data will be stored as strings.
You can execute query `CREATE TABLE(uId INT PRIMARY KEY, linkList BlahBlahString);` 
without any error. Data type in SQLite is for sql compability only

Answer (score 8):

Yor have 2 choices to store a long `String` in  `SQLite`

1. `TEXT` type - SQLite support very long text (I don't know exact number but I tested *33000* char SQLite3)
2. `BLOB` type: You can use `BLOB` Data type to hold long String.

Comment: what is the length limit for BLOB ? (that too without much performance lag.)

Comment: Text stores non-Unicode data of variable length, with a maximum length of 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647) characters.

Answer (score 1):

Size limit for TEXT (VARCHAR and others TEXT alike) are defaulted to 100 0000 000 Bytes
look for macro `SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH`

Can be increase (or decrease, but no gain to do that aside of code sanity maybe)
using 
`int sqlite3_limit(sqlite3 *db, int limitId, int newLimit)`
using `SQLITE_LIMIT_LENGTH` for `limitId`.

Again: aside of a need for more than ~100MB (or code sanity by trowing execption) I don't see any interest to modify default.