# SQLite Datatypes for use in MS Access

Tags: sqlite, ms-access-2010

I am attempting to recreate many fairly large access databases [about 20 mil records over 8 databases] into a single SQLite DB, and then link to that data in my main MS access DB [full of user entered data and links to all the large tables and stuff]

i can create the big tables in SQLite just fine, Access can link to it, bring up the tables, but all the field types are coming through as Memo, which of course cannot be joined to

The majority of fields are sitting as Text fields in SQLIte

Any way to avoid them linking as Memo fields?

so, the majority of the fields are alphanumeric and i put them all as Text as they mainly as ID fields i'm linking, they are all CSV extracts directly out of Salesforce, below is the smallest one, these would all be normally imported access as Text fields, in SQLite they come import as Text fields, but linking from SQLite to access, they come across as memo

Sample data is

```
"Id","CreatedById","CreatedDate","End_Date__c","Future_Sale_Cycle__c","IsDeleted","LastModifiedById","LastModifiedDate","LastReferencedDate","LastViewedDate","Name","OwnerId","Start_Date__c","SystemModstamp"
"a4N900000004PXrEAM","005900000041XdPAAU","2015-05-29T06:20:07.000Z","2016-02-13","a4N6F000000L34HUAS","false","00590000003cQMIAA2","2016-02-12T00:22:23.000Z","2016-02-14T23:02:02.000Z","2016-02-14T23:02:02.000Z","YPSEL2-36","00590000003cQMIAA2","2015-02-23","2016-04-22T11:07:45.000Z"
```

the text fields i join on are either 9, 12 15 or 18 digit alphanumeric, always, they are always ID fields, mixes of letters and numbers

Comment: What text size are your SQLite fields? If > 255, they will be interpreted as Memo. // Joining on text fields (instead of numbers) raises an alarm for me, but if you must, these text fields should be *small*.

Comment: so, the majority of the fields are alphanumeric and i put them all as Text as they mainly as ID fields i'm linking, they are all CSV extracts directly out of Salesforce, below is the smallest one, these would all be normally imported access as Text fields, in SQLite they come import as Text fields, but linking from SQLite to access, they come across as memo

Sample data is
CreatedById,CreatedDate,End_Date__c
005900000041XdPAAU,2015-05-29T06:20:07.000Z,13/02/2016

Comment: the text field i join on are either 9, 12 15 or 18 digit alphanumeric, always, they are always ID fields, mixes of letters and numbers

Comment: Please add the SQLite table definition that matches that sample data. Also the MS Access table definition of that table would  would be helpful. I can then see what the corresponding column definitions are.

Comment: What @RyanVincent wrote - this is what I was asking too. :)  The question is not how much data actually is stored in the fields, but how large they are defined.

Comment: All good, sorted it out, was my first time using sqlite, wasn't setting the text size, Thanks for the hints!

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer so that it helps us. Seriously, I have no idea how you did it and would really like to know. Or at least explain what ``wasn't setting the text size,`` really means.

Answer (score 1):

This is all a bit confusing.

According to [Whats the best SQLite data type for a long string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755803/whats-the-best-sqlite-data-type-for-a-long-string) , SQLite only has one text datatype (TEXT), with no length restrictions.

But when I create a table in a new SQLite database with

```
sqlite> create table t1 (id integer primary key, txt varchar(20));
```

and link that table via [ODBC](http://ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/) into Access, the `txt` column has the datatype `Text(20)`. And I can join on that column.
`TEXT` columns on the other hand are linked as `Memo`.

So: Since you are creating the SQLite database yourself, I suggest creating the text fields as `varchar(255)` or smaller.

---

**But note:** in my example table, I can happily insert larger strings than 20 chars:

```
sqlite> insert into t1 values (7, 'dings');
sqlite> insert into t1 values (8, 'dingsaaaaabbbbbccccc');
sqlite> insert into t1 values (9, 'dingsaaaaabbbbbcccccddddd');
sqlite> select * from t1;
7|dings
8|dingsaaaaabbbbbccccc
9|dingsaaaaabbbbbcccccddddd
```

But in Access I only get 20 chars:

```
id  txt
7   dings
8   dingsaaaaabbbbbccccc
9   dingsaaaaabbbbbccccc
```

Therefore my recommendation of `varchar(255)`, even if your strings will be much smaller.

Answer (score 0):

I have a combination MS-Access 2010 database with linked SQL tables - and experience the same effect that you do.

The only way I've been able to get around it is to create queries for each of the tables that I want to join. For each of the fixed length text fields, I create a new field using the `Left$` function.

Then instead of joining directly to your SQLITE tables, use these queries to join link fields with your regular Access tables.

So for your examples above you could add these fields to your query

```
LinkID: Left$([ID], 18)
LinkCreatedByID: Left$([CreatedById], 18)
LinkOwnerId: Left$([OwnerId], 18)
LinkName: Left$([Name], 9)
```

Hope that helps